# how to define a list of variable number of objects in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am learning groovy, I am using the [documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html) and some youtube videos. I want for testing to find out how to declare an array of objects, but that array will have a `x` number of objects depending on some stuff. Here is what I tried:

```
class Issue {
    String type = ""
    String severity = ""
    String linestart = "" 
    String filename = "" 
    String meesage = "" 
}

def test(){
    Issue[] Issues = new Issue[5] 
    Issues[0].type = "error"
    println Issues[0].type
}

test()
```

what I get:

```
Caught: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot set property 'type' on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot set property 'type' on null object
```

I assume my array does not have 5 Issues objects inside, and that is why is trying to set on null object. How would be the right syntax to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right- all the values are initially `null`. You have to first create instances of `Issue` and assign it to the array elements,

```
Issues[0] = new Issue()
Issues[0].type = "error"
```

alternatively, using "groovy" syntax,

```
Issues[0] = new Issue(type: "error")
```

Comment: thanks for answering. I am wondering now if it is better to use a class or a map for this case...and how to create a list of maps

Comment: peronally, i would use a list of objects here,  `List<Issue> issues` You have a well defined class which is preferable to using a map of properties